# Manipulating a Triangle Array and then Plotting in 3D in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, 3d

I have written the code below to show a quantum walk which is essentially a probability distribution on a numberline for a "coin flip". The function "get_p(N)" generates an array of the probability values for all the possible positions on the line after N moves.

```
N=10
def get_p(N):
    P = 2*N+1    # number of positions
    # do all your p stuff here
    #defining a quantum coin
    coin0 = array([1, 0])  # |0>
    coin1 = array([0, 1])  # |1>
    #defining the coin operator
    C00 = outer(coin0, coin0)  # |0><0| 
    C01 = outer(coin0, coin1)  # |0><1| 
    C10 = outer(coin1, coin0)  # |1><0| 
    C11 = outer(coin1, coin1)  # |1><1|
    C_hat = (C00 + C01 + C10 - C11)/sqrt(2.)
    #step operator
    ShiftPlus = roll(eye(P), 1, axis=0)
    ShiftMinus = roll(eye(P), -1, axis=0)
    S_hat = kron(ShiftPlus, C00) + kron(ShiftMinus, C11)
    #walk operator
    U = S_hat.dot(kron(eye(P), C_hat))
    #defining the initial state
    posn0 = zeros(P)
    posn0[N] = 1     # array indexing starts from 0, so index N is the central posn
    psi0 = kron(posn0,(coin0+coin1*1j)/sqrt(2.))
    #the state after N steps
    psiN = linalg.matrix_power(U, N).dot(psi0)   

    prob = empty(P)
    for k in range(P):
        posn = zeros(P)
        posn[k] = 1     
        M_hat_k = kron( outer(posn,posn), eye(2))
        proj = M_hat_k.dot(psiN)
        prob[k] = proj.dot(proj.conjugate()).real
    return prob

Z = []
for i in range(N):
    Z.append(get_p(i))

X = arange(2*N+1)
Y = arange(N)
```

Z is essentially a triangle array (if you imagine when N=0 the probability will be 1 in the centre, then there is 3 positions possible after that and so on). 
Printing Z when N=3 gives:

```
[array([ 1.]), array([ 0.5,  0. ,  0.5]), array([ 0.25,  0.  ,  0.5 ,  0.  ,  0.25])]
```

So my question is how can I manipulate these so I can plot them? [This](http://ej.iop.org/images/1367-2630/12/12/123018/Full/nj359958fig1.jpg) is an image of what the finished article should look like.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Z` 'array' is actually a list of numpy arrays of different lengths.

I think it would be better to define Z as a single array filled with zeros before hand and then fill it with your values. Maybe like this:

```
Z=np.zeros((10,19))
for i in range(N):
    x = coin.get_p(i)
    l = len(x) 
    Z[i,0:l] = x
```

As regards the plot, it's not clear to me what you want exactly. Try looking at the examples here:

http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/index.html